# Change CSS Stylesheet when checkbox is marked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I was trying to create a checkbox in HTML which changes the current stylesheet to another one using JS.

The style didn't change after i checked the checkbox.
Here is the error message I got:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4DMS.png)

Here is the code I have written:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Normal Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link id="pageStyle" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
        function swapStyleSheet(sheet) {

        if (document.getElementById("lightSwitch").checked == true) {

        document.getElementById("pageStyle").set.Attribute('href', sheet) = "dark.css";

            } 
        else {

        document.getElementById("pageStyle").set.Attribute('href', sheet) = "style.css";

            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

        <input onclick="swapStyleSheet()" id="lightSwitch" type="checkbox" name="lightSwitch">

</body>
```

Thanks for clarifying the problem for me.

Comment: But what happened?

Comment: Typo. It is one property: `setAttribute` not `Attribute` of `set`. Remove the `.`

Comment: Set attribute method is not valid function must be setAttribute
document.getElementById("pageStyle").setAttribute('href', sheet) = "dark.css";

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like:

```
...
<script>
function swapStyleSheet() {
    if (document.getElementById("lightSwitch").checked) {
        document.getElementById("pageStyle").setAttribute('href', 'dark.css');
    } else {
        document.getElementById("pageStyle").setAttribute('href', "style.css");
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input onclick="swapStyleSheet()" id="lightSwitch" type="checkbox" name="lightSwitch">
</body>
```

swapStyleSheet does not get any attribute as you are calling it with no attributes `onclick="swapStyleSheet()"`.

setAttribute is method that receives 2 attributes. You cannot assign to method result as you did here `Attribute('href', sheet) = "style.css";`

Otherwise looks good (did not test it though).

Answer (score 0):

`.set.Attribute` is not valid JavaScript. Use `.setAttribute`. Also you can not set your attributes and then assign it within the same line `.set.Attribute('href', sheet) = "dark.css"`. And you're using a parameter within your JavaScript function `function swapStyleSheet(sheet)` but not doing anything with it when you call your function `onclick="swapStyleSheet()"`.

Since the `.css` files aren't shared, there is no way to test this. But try changing your code to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Normal Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link id="pageStyle" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     <script>
        function swapStyleSheet() {

        if (document.getElementById("lightSwitch").checked == true) {

        document.getElementById("pageStyle").setAttribute('href', "dark.css");

            } 
        else {

        document.getElementById("pageStyle").setAttribute('href', "style.css");

            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

        <input onclick="swapStyleSheet()" id="lightSwitch" type="checkbox" name="lightSwitch">

</body>
```

I cleaned up your attribute methods and removed the unneeded parameter. Hopefully this should help get you in the right direction.

Answer (score -2):

You are doing it wrong:

This is your code (explained)

```
<script>
    function swapStyleSheet(sheet) {
// This is expecting a parameter (the stylesheet you want, I suppose)

    if (document.getElementById("lightSwitch").checked == true) {

    document.getElementById("pageStyle").set.Attribute('href', sheet) = "dark.css"; //Here you are, first, invoking a function (wrong function because it's setAttribute and not set.Attribute) and then assigning it a value "dark.css"

        } 
    else {

    document.getElementById("pageStyle").set.Attribute('href', sheet) = "style.css";
//Same here

        }
    }
</script>
```

Your code should look somehow similar to this (there are multiple ways to attach event listeners but this is following the same structure you had):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Normal Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link id="pageStyle" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
        function swapStyleSheet(sheet) {

        if (document.getElementById("lightSwitch").getAttribute('checked') === true) {

        document.getElementById("pageStyle").setAttribute('href', "dark.css");

            } 
        else {

        document.getElementById("pageStyle").setAttribute('href', "style.css");

            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <input onclick="swapStyleSheet()" id="lightSwitch" type="checkbox" name="lightSwitch">

</body>
```

Comment: Where is "sheet" defination or value assigned. Thats basic of javascript

Comment: In this case I didn't use it. I could have even removed it from the parameters' list, since he is deciding what stylesheet he is going to use depending on the checkbox status.